# Wordpress insert data from front end to custom table using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert data into WordPress database by creating a new table from a plugin.I use a shortcode to generate the form I have created the table but when I try to insert the data from form, it does not insert the data. Can someone help me on this?

**Here is my code:-**

```
function insert_into_employee_db() {
        global $wpdb;
        $page_link = get_permalink();

        // starts output buffering
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <style>
        form#v_form>input {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        <form action="" method="post" id="v_form">

            <input type="text" name="total_employee" id="total_employee" placeholder="Total Employee" />
            <input type="text" name="present_employee" id="present_employee" placeholder="Present Today" />
            <input type="text" name="br_manager" id="br_manager"  placeholder="Manager Name"/>
            <input type="number" name="br_code" id="br_code"  placeholder="Branch Code"/>
            <input type="text" name="br_name" id="br_name"  placeholder="Branch Name"/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        // does the inserting, in case the form is filled and submitted
        if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["total_employee"] != "" ) {
            $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."sbl_employee";

            $time               = date("d/m/Y");
            $total_employee     = $_POST["total_employee"];
            $present_employee   = $_POST["present_employee"];
            $br_manager         = $_POST["br_manager"];
            $br_code            = $_POST["br_code"];
            $br_name            = $_POST["br_name"];
            $data = array(
                        'time'              => date('dd-mm-YY'),
                        'total_employee'    => (int)$total_employee,
                        'present_employee'  => (int)$present_employee,
                        'br_manager'        => $br_manager,
                        'br_code'           => (int)$br_code,
                        'br_name'           => $br_name,
                       );


            $format = array(
                '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'
            );
            $success=$wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data, $format );
            if($success){
                $html = "<p>Successfully Saved. <a href=".$page_link.">Update? </a></p>";
            }else{
                $html = "failed. ". $wpdb->show_errors();
            }
        }
        // if the form is submitted but the name is empty
        if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["total_employee"] == "" )
            $html .= "<p>You need to fill the required fields.</p>";
        // outputs everything
        return $html;
    }
    // adds a shortcode you can use: [insert-employee]
    add_shortcode('insert_employee', 'insert_into_employee_db');
```

**and here is my db create function**

```
function sbl_employee_create_db() {

    global $wpdb;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_employee  = $wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_employee';
    $table_br_name   = $wpdb->prefix . 'sbl_br_name';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_employee (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        total_employee smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        present_employee smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        br_manager varchar(5) NOT NULL,
        br_code smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        br_name varchar(120) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
//do action when plugin active
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sbl_employee_create_db' );
```

Comment: are you getting any error? Did you enable the debug mode?

Comment: I do not but i am having strong feeling that your format is wrong you are passing the string every where while you have set the value as an integer that may be causing this issue

Comment: I checked that without declaring the string and also enabled debug ...and no error show. it say failed .1

Comment: try with my format and see what happens

Comment: Have a look at the comments on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/ as they explain some idiosyncrasies with dbDelta()

Comment: @jeff thanks I solved ! there was an error with the db col limit and the data I am trying to insert . `br_manager varchar(5) NOT NULL,` should be `br_manager varchar(200) NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 0):

Try this format and let me know what happen with new format?

```
$format = array(
            '%s', '%d', '%d', '%s', '%d', '%s'
          );
```

Comment: same result noting insert into db.

Comment: Possible format values: %s as string; %d as integer ? sure I have done this but failed